# Is the activation energy higher in incomplete combustion or in complete combustion?

Tags: combustion

I am looking into high school level chemistry where it is asked if the incomplete combustion of methane into carbon monoxide has a higher activation energy then its complete combustion.

My reasoning is somewhat empirical, if there is enough oxygen, complete combustion is preferred. From which I think I can deduce that the activation energy of incomplete combustion must be higher. But is this correct? And even so does this reasoning constitute a general heuristic for activation energy in complete vs incomplete combustion?